# Web app push notification

Tags: html, notifications, web, push

I'm going to make a web app using html5. 
The app are going to be able to send a push notification to the phone even if the web app isn't used. Is this possible?

Comment: You haven't really provided enough information to get a good answer. In general a program on the web *server* sends push notifications...

Comment: Is it pobbible for the webserver to send push notifications to Ios and Android. And if possible is it difficult to do?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. How difficult it is really depends on your level of ability with server-side programming, your server platform, etc. Once again I don't really have enough information to help you.

Comment: There is simple guide along with code as well, its not that hard what you think https://deskiz.com/blog/web-push-notifications-integration-anywhere-easiest-guide/

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible natively in browsers yet, though W3C standards for browser-based push notifications are finalizing this year.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/eventsource/

The only options are to:

- wait for Apple, Google, etc to implement the W3C recommendations in their browsers (if I were to guess, probably late 2012, early 2013)
- have users install a native app that pushes notifications on behalf of your web app (like AlertRocket)
- use SMS text messages through an SMS subscription service

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Google Chrome allows for cloud messaging (GCM).

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/cloudMessaging